# Finding Eigenvalues of matrix with sum of all rows being equal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$\begin{bmatrix}
101 & 2 &3  &4  &5 \\ 
1 & 102 &3  &4  &5 \\ 
1 & 2 & 103 &4  &5 \\ 
 1& 2 &3  &104  &5 \\ 
1 & 2 &3  &4  & 105
\end{bmatrix}$

Sum of all rows of this matrix is 115 hence $\exists \lambda = 115$

Now is there any property that can be used to find out remaining eigenvalues of this matrix?

remaining 4 eigenvalues are 100.

Comment: another property is that the trace is the sum of all eigenvalues.

Comment: that tells us sum of remaining eigenvalues is 400 but i can't guess from that the remaining all are 100

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be your matrix and let$$B=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4&5\\1&2&3&4&5\\1&2&3&4&5\\1&2&3&4&5\\1&2&3&4&5\end{bmatrix};$$then $A=B+100\operatorname{Id}$. Since the dimension of the space spanned by the columns of $B$ is $1$ and since $B$ is a $5\times5$ matrix, the characteristic polynomial of $B$ is of the type $x^4(a-x)=ax^4-x^5$, for some $a\in\mathbb R$. On the other hand, by the same argument that you used, $15$ is an eigenvalue of $B$. Therefore, the eigenvalues of $B$ are $0$ ($4$ times) and $15$. So, the eigenvalues of $A$ are $100$ ($4$ times) and $115$.